# Cluster Hazelcast wso2 APIM 2.0 - Load Balance Sticky

Tags: api, wso2, hazelcast, wso2-api-manager

First I would like to thanks a lot for this forum.

I have a doubt about the cluster configuration with Hazelcast and Load Balance.

In the documentation https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+the+Gateway

```
in section load balance configuration appear: 
   upstream wso2.am.com {
        **sticky cookie JSESSIONID;**
        server xxx.xxx.xxx.xx4:9763;
        server xxx.xxx.xxx.xx5:9763;
}
```

Why to use sticky if the cluster already make the session control?

My understanding is wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

In APIM, hazelcast clustering is used for cache invalidation among nodes, inter-node communication for dep-sync etc, but not for session replication. Therefore you need sticky sessions.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.